# polars map_elements infers nested list column type as null instead of int

Tags: python-polars

Trying to apply polars map_elements to a column of nested lists, the first element in the series is a nested empty list which causes the dtype to be inferred as List[List[Null]] despite specifying the return dtype. Any suggestions or workarounds?

```
s = pl.Series("a", [[[]], [[1, 2]]])
s.map_elements(lambda x: x, return_dtype=pl.List(pl.List(pl.Int64)))
```

returns

```
Series: 'a' [list[list[null]]]
[
    [[]]
    [[null, null]]
]
```

Expected output

```
Series: 'a' [list[list[int64]]]
[
    [[]]
    [[1, 2]]
]
```

Comment: It's not the map_elements in this case, check `print(s)` - you would need to pass `dtype=` at construction time it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to run `Series.map_elements`? simple [`Series.cast`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.cast.html) seems to be working:

```py
s = pl.Series("a", [[[]], [[1, 2]]])
s.cast(pl.List(pl.List(pl.Int64)))

Series: 'a' [list[list[i64]]]
[
    [[]]
    [[null, null]]
]
```

Comment: I think it was just an example to simulate the calling of a UDF (and their real function does something else). The example is bugged though because `1, 2` gets lost when the series is created so it's unclear what the real issue is.

Comment: Yes I'm actually applying a dictionary (string to int)